# Can't call extension method in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ado.net

I defined this extension method in a module in the XXXDBTools project:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module Extensions
...
''' <summary>
''' Executes a non-query SQL statement and returns the number of rows affected.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="transaction">The DB transaction.</param>
''' <param name="sql">The SQL statement.</param>
''' <returns>The number of rows affected.</returns>
<Extension>
Public Function ExecuteSqlNonQuery(ByVal transaction As SqlTransaction, ByVal sql As String) As Integer
    ' create and open connection
    Using conn As SqlConnection = DBFunctions.GetConnection(transaction)
        if transaction Is Nothing then conn.Open()

        ' create command
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
            ' read data
            Dim result As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            ' clean up
            if transaction is Nothing Then conn.Close()
            Return result
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
End Module
```

Now I want to call the method in my main XXX project:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="XXXDBTools" %>
...
Dim trans As SqlTransaction = DBFunctions.BeginTransaction()
trans.ExecuteSqlNonQuery(sqlStr)
```

However when I do so, I get this compile error:

> 'ExecuteSqlNonQuery' is not a member of 'SqlTransaction'

Why is this? Everything looks set up properly so I can call the extension method - why would I get an error? Surely I'm missing something obvious...

Answer (score 1):

Aha, as soon as I write it down and step away to grab some coffee, I figure it out!

The `Module Extensions` needed to be declared as `Public`.

Comment: Glad you figured it out but I am concerned about the query. Does it have any values being inserted or updated? Have you concatenated these values into the query? If so this is a bad practice because it opens up your database to Sql Injection. You should use Parameters.